# How to make my slackbot reply in a thread, instead of to entire channel in Slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I am doing slack to ServiceNow integration which is working fine. I am trying to reply to a thread instead of posting a message to a channel.

Currently i am using `https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage` which is reply to a channel but not to a thread. I tried looking document but not able to find the an api to reply a thread.

Can anyone please help me the right api to reply to a thread instead of to a channel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional parameter to that method called `thread_ts` which lets you specify a parent message `ts` to which you'd like your message added as a threaded reply.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage